# Ansible save only when previous ios_config task was changed

Tags: ansible

Id like to ask for some help with having a task trigger only when the previous ios_config task was changed. Ive see some plays where the result.changed was used however, ios_config doesnt allow me to register.

Comment: _"ios_config doesnt allow me to register"_ – why is that? If you can see something in ansible stdout log, you can register it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `ios_command` does not allow you to register ? which error do you get ?

Example of test reachability to an NTP server:

```
- name: ping ntp server 4.5.6.7
  ios_command:
    provider: "{{ provider }}"
    commands:
      - ping 4.5.6.7
  register: pingntp

- name: set ntp server 4.5.6.7
  ios_config:
    lines:
      - ntp server 4.5.6.7 key 8888 source Loopback0
    match: line
    provider: "{{ provider }}"
  when: pingntp.stdout[0].count('!') > 0
```